# Is there any issue with Steward badge?

Tags: support, review, badges

I received back to back notification for earning Steward badges for the same reasons:

[image]

You can see there are total 13 Steward badges have been awarded in last one hour multiple times for same review type:

[image]

Is there any bug with Steward badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug; it's part of an update to the review queues. You now get one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a single queue. For more details, see [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.